# Problem validating state of database before commit of version

Tags: database, flyway

I'm playing around with [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and amongst other things, I would like to verify certain things in the database before committing the version. As an example, I would like the following migration to fail:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TABLE TMP.DUMMY(x int) @

create or replace procedure TMP.DOUBLE_DUMMY()
begin
    update TMP.DUMMY set x = 2*x;
end @

-- TMP.DOUBLE_DUMMY() is invalidated
DROP TABLE TMP.DUMMY @
```

This is easy enough to detect since I can try to recompile invalidated procedures as:

```
for c1 as c1 cursor for
    select rtrim(procschema) || '.' || rtrim(procname) as p
        ,  rtrim(procschema) || '.' || rtrim(specificname) as s
        ,  text
    from syscat.procedures
    where procschema = in_schema
      and valid <> 'Y'
      and language = 'SQL'
    order by create_time
do
    execute immediate 'drop specific procedure ' || s;
    execute immediate text;
end for;
```

and if something is broken, recompilation of the procedure fails. However, I can't seem to find a callback that can be used after the last statement in the file, but before the new version is inserted and committed.

The next idea I got was to create a trigger on the flyway version table. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FLYWAY.IRA_FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY
AFTER INSERT ON FLYWAY.FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
    CALL COMPILE_SCHEMAS();
END @
```

However, it turns out that flyway uses one connection for the statements in the file and one connection for the version table. This leads to a lock timeout since there is an X lock on the object when the recompile appears.

I can't seem to find some property that would prevent Flyway to use two connections. From a logical perspective, it seems counter-intuitive to use two transactions for one unit of work. I can't imagine a situation where you would like to commit one and rollback the other.

Any other thoughts on how to inject such a control mechanism, without having to put the control inside the migration files?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem here. If something went wrong in the script then the migration fails. if you want to do additionnal steps to verify that no procedure is invalidated after your migration then call your verification bloc at the end of each script or use the callback afterEachMigrate.

Comment: After reading your comment I did a test, and it appears as if afterEachMigrate actually runs before the version is committed. If this is correct (I'll test it a bit more), it will actually work the way I want it to do. I - wrongly - assumed that afterEachMigrate ran after the version was committed. If you add an answer explaining this I will accept and upvote it. This is probably why there are two transactions as well. If you don't want to make an answer out of it I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afterEachMigrate actually works that way. The trick is that the commit of the version is a separate transaction, which waits for afterEachMigrate to finish.